# Is there a to change the value of an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the value of an element on a third-party web page using a JavaScript Add-on to display a hyperlink

I already have the link on the page i would like to be able to click it
I think I'm on the right track using `document.getElementById` although I'm not sure how to then change the id into a "a href" and then how to pass it back into the value.

Sorry, this is a bit of a tricky situation so I'll try my best to explain it. On a third-party web-page which we use for our HR related tasks, there is a section titled "File Link" although this isn't a link. When you copy and paste the address into a browser it displays the file. What i am trying to do is create a hyperlink on the "File Link" section to remove the need to copy and paste the link. Because this is a third party website. We have access to the JavaScript on the website and need to change the address into a hyperlink. I'm not entirely sure this is possible.The element id is "__C_cb_file_link" and i would like to insert the link address into the element using a variable then add the link parameters into the variable then reinsert it into the element/value.

```js
function linkIt() {        
        var intoLink = document.getElementById("__C_cb_file_link");  
        var hLink = "<a href="+intoLink+"</a>;  
        intoLink.value = hLink;  
 }  
window.onload = linkIt();
```

```html
<td><div class="sui-disabled" title="">m-files://view/37FF751C-A23F-4233-BD8B-243834E67731/0-46524?object=C46A7624-D24B-45F3-A301-5117EFC1F674</div>
<input type="hidden" name="__C_cb_file_link" id="__C_cb_file_link" value="m-files://view/37FF751C-A23F-4233-BD8B-243834E67731/0-46524?object=C46A7624-D24B-45F3-A301-5117EFC1F674"/></td></tr>
```

Comment: "_on a web page_" What exactly is this web page, a third-party page in an iframe? Or are you working with an add-on or contentscript?

Comment: @Teemu Sorry i will edit the original post, it's a third party web page, i can't change the page itself but i can use javascript it on. Its for our companies web based HR program

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML. Also...if this is not your page, how are you proposing to execute the script? As teemu asked, are you doing it via an iFrame, or a browser add-on or something?

Comment: @ADyson I am using a browser add-on, I've add a snippet of the HTML in question. please let me know if you need any more information. I've also added more information into the description to try and be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code:

1) The code snippet in your question doesn't run because of a missing `"` at the end of the second line of the linkIt() function.

2) `intoLink` is a hidden field so anything you add to it will not be visible in the page

3) Even if point 2 were not true, setting the `value` of a form field will not cause HTML to appear on the page (at best you might get some plain text in a textbox).

4) `"<a href="+intoLink+"</a>"` doesn't work because `intoLink` is a complex object which represents the entire hidden field element (not just its value property). You can't convert a whole object into a string directly. You need to extract the `value` of the field.

---

A better way to do this is by creating a new element for the hyperlink and appending it to the page in a suitable place. Also I recommend not adding your event via `onload` - when written using this syntax only one onload event can exist in a page at once. Since you're amending another page which isn't under your control you don't want to disable any other load events which might be defined. Use `addEventListener` instead, which allows multiple handlers to be specified for the same event.

Demo:

```js
function linkIt() {
  var intoLink = document.getElementById("__C_cb_file_link");
  var hLink = document.createElement("a");
  hLink.setAttribute("href", intoLink.value);
  hLink.innerHTML = "Click here";
  intoLink.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', hLink);
}
window.addEventListener('load', linkIt);
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="sui-disabled" title="">m-files://view/37FF751C-A23F-4233-BD8B-243834E67731/0-46524?object=C46A7624-D24B-45F3-A301-5117EFC1F674</div>
  <input type="hidden" name="__C_cb_file_link" id="__C_cb_file_link" value="m-files://view/37FF751C-A23F-4233-BD8B-243834E67731/0-46524?object=C46A7624-D24B-45F3-A301-5117EFC1F674" /></td>
</tr>
```

P.S. `m-files://` is not a standard protocol in most browsers, unless some kind of extension has been installed, so even when you turn it into a hyperlink it may not work for everyone.

Comment: Thank you so much, after tweaking the code slightly and the permissions on the website I've now managed to add an option to launch the link with the M-Files application. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In below code first we read input value with new link (however we can read this value from other html tags), then we remove this element (and button) and add to parent element (of removed input) the new link

```js
function linkIt() {
  let intoLink = __C_cb_file_link.value;
  let parent  = __C_cb_file_link.parentNode;
  __C_cb_file_link.remove();
  btn.remove();
  parent.innerHTML += `<a href="${intoLink}">${intoLink}</a>`; 
}
```

```html
<input id="__C_cb_file_link" value="https://example.com">
<button id="btn" onclick="linkIt()">Link It</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE] I supose that your "__C_cb_file_link" was a paragraph so I get the previous text http://mylink.com and create a link with,  is it what you want, right?

```js
function linkIt() {     

            let fileLink = document.getElementById("__C_cb_file_link");
            let hLink = fileLink.textContent;
            fileLink.innerHTML =  "<a href="+hLink+">"+hLink+"</a>";
                        
    }  
      linkIt();
```

```html
<div>  
     <p id="__C_cb_file_link">http://myLink.com</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I already have the link on the page i just want to make it clickable

Comment: So you want to convert your text into a link right? pls, show your HTML that will be much more easy todo this, because I want to know if you have a tag <a> or just the text and which one tag is  "__C_cb_file_link"

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit of a tricky situation so I'll try my best to explain it. On a third-party webpage which we use for our HR related tasks, there is a section titled "File Link" although this isn't a link. When you copy and paste the address into a browser it displays the file. What i am trying to do is create a hyperlink on the "File Link" section to remove the need to copy and paste the link. Because this is a third party website. We have access to the JavaScript on the website and need to change the address into a hyperlink. I'm not entirely sure this is possible

Comment: The element id is "__C_cb_file_link" and i would like to insert the link address into the element using a variable then add the link parameters into the variable then reinsert it into the element/value